# How can I express the idea that the content of a book is all about a certain topic, say the oil industry?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, sentence-request

How can I express the idea that the content of a book is all about a certain topic, say the oil industry?

My first reaction was to use 'be dedicated to', but  that phrase is used only when the author wrote the book for someone's case or in memory of someone.

Comment: how about "This book concerns the oil industry", or "This book solely concerns the oil industry" to empasize that it's only topic is the oil industry.

Comment: In what context is this sentence to exist?  Is it the first sentence of a book review in the New York Times? Is it a blurb by the author intended to be in a couple of line summary of the box on a book-selling site?  Are you telling a friend that your read an interesting book that was all about the oil industry?

Comment: The answer may be in the question.  _"(the book) is all about (a certain topic)"_  That's fine.  Are you looking for a more concise way to say it?  Like "this is an oil industry book", or "it's about/on the oil industry"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Very simply, "the book is about the oil industry".  This covers most cases.

If you want to emphasise this you can use adverbs such as "only" or "solely". You could say, "the book only contains information about the oil industry, and ignores other fossil fuels." "This book is solely concerned with the oil industry."

Comment: 'about' doesn't quite capture the 'all about'. on the other hand i think 'all about' would be kinda informal. hmmm.....

Comment: @BCLC in addition to being somewhat informal, the phrase 'all about' means the book is a broad/comprehensive overview of the oil industry, not necessarily that no other topics are covered. "This book is all about the oil industry" is different from "All of this book is about the oil industry"

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways:

- "[book] is devoted to" or "entirely devoted to"
- "[book] gives a comprehensive overview of the oil industry and its history"
- "[book] comprises a thorough exposition and analysis of the oil industry"

Answer (score 3):

1. 'This book's main topic is the oil industry.'
2. 'This book's primary focus is the oil industry.'

How are these?

Comment: Those phrases imply that the book also briefly touches on other topics, which is fine if true, but problematic otherwise. For example, I would expect a book with that description to at least briefly discuss renewables, climate change, etc. because those are all relevant to the current state of the oil industry. OTOH, if you say that the book is *only* about the oil industry, then omitting those things would be expected.

Answer (score 1):

How about "monograph"?

According to [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/monograph), "monograph" means "*a highly detailed and thoroughly documented study or paper written about a limited area of a subject or field of inquiry*".

Comment: A monograph is usually a scholarly work, not a popular or semi-popular work. A monograph is normally written by an expert with qualifications in the field. A monograph is normally intended for a technically qualified, expert readership. I would only use the term for works that have these characteristics.